# build.py works when called from Shell but not when called from Eclipse

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, embedded

Operating system is Kali Linux and I am using Eclipse for embedded C/C++.

When I try to build the project which calls `python3 build.py -develop` it looks as if Eclipse cannot find cmake and mbed-tools. Below is the output in the console window:

```
python3 build.py -develop 
sh: 1: mbed-tools: not found
sh: 1: cmake: not found
sh: 1: cmake: not found
Updating mbed tools config...
Updating cmake config...
Building...

06:08:21 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.71ms)
```

However it hasn't actually built anything.

The path for cmake and mbed-tools is added to the $PATH variable. And I can successfully build the project if I manually type in the build command into a shell window.

I am stumped as to why it doesn't work when called from Eclipse.

Comment: Did you edit your system's PATH _after_ launching Eclipse? If so, restart it. No running program receives a changed environment variable automatically.

Comment: Note that Kali Linux is not intended for general purpose use, it is for penetration testing only. Because of that lots of things are much harder to do than on other versions of Linux. [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/56152)

Comment: I was originally using Ubuntu but it doesn't work well with the laptop I am using (Acer Aspire E5-575). The video is extremely laggy. After doing a bunch of searching and finding other people with the same problem I decided to try a different distro. Kali runs much better on it than Ubuntu did.

Comment: @thebusybee PATH was edited before launching Eclipse. I have also tried restarting several times to no success.

Comment: Now you need to check how the PATHs of the shell of your console window and sh (as used by Eclipse apparently) differ. And if sh has a reduced list, why this is. -- Or did you fiddle with the environment variables in Eclipse? -- OT: To get better performance, you could try lighter versions of Ubuntu, for example Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Are you aware that you can install multiple desktops?

Comment: I didn't change any environment variables in Eclipse. How do I check the PATH of sh? I'm only have limited experience with Linux. The reason for the poor performance with Ubuntu as I understand it is because of lack of support with the particular Intel chipset this laptop uses.

Comment: `echo $PATH` -- I don't think that Ubuntu on a current laptop works so bad, we are using it on more than 10 year old devices. Anyway, the performance issue is a topic for another SE site.

Comment: Your tags are confusing.  The question appears to be about running an embedded build on a Linux host, but the tags might suggest embedded-lunux.  Neither is it really about python.  It is largely about _using_ Linux rather than either _programming_ for Linux or embedded, or in Python.

Comment: What tags would you suggest? I included Python in the tags because of build.py which uses python.